# Making uncountable nouns plural vs regular plural nouns

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

> There are several different types of happiness.
> There are many different kinds of government.
> There are many types of golf balls.

Since we are talking about different types of happiness would you need to make it plural (happinesses). I know it’s an uncountable noun, but it’s confusing. My question for the second is pretty much the same as I want to know if it should be government or governments. And the third sentence I know is correct, but it’s made plural unlike the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct. 'Happiness' does not need to be plural because it's saying that happiness (singular) can be several different things. The second sentence can go both ways: in its current form, it's saying that 'government' (singular), meaning the governing of a population, can be done many ways. Writing 'governments' (plural) is talking about the government body itself - the people who govern the population. The third sentence is also correct, as 'golf ball' cannot be a general term.